# What is the correct way to loop through this block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this block inside rails console.

```
@idea = Idea.find_by(rand(1...Idea.count))
@roundid = Faker::Number.between(1, 3)
@idea.round_id = @roundid
```

I am trying trying to update seven database rows. And I have used a code below.

```
7.times do
 @idea = Idea.find_by(rand(1...Idea.count))
 @roundid = Faker::Number.between(1, 3)
 @idea.round_id = @roundid
end
```

it does not do what I expect. Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately I cannot parse your question. :( Could you give more details on how this code behaves differently then you would expect?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I guess you need 3 rows and 7 columns right? If so then you will need two loops. Or please clear it more so we can help.

Comment: Sorry! Of course.

I am trying to get a random Idea, via it's id, and then assign a round_id to that id with options 1, 2, or 3. If I am inside rails console, an idea starts with round_id = nil. When I type out each line, I get 1 random idea, 1 random round_id, and that random idea gets assigned the random round_id. If however, I paste the whole block, with the 7.times do, all I get back is "7". What I expected, was at least 7 attempts of getting random ideas with random round_ids. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your code does put a random `roundid` to a random `Idea` 7 times, but the block returns 7. Stock the `@idea` in a array and return it to see the results

Comment: Also this assumes that all the ids will be between 1 and Idea.count which means no deletions of any ideas otherwise there will be ideas outside this range. As we all know some ideas are bad ideas and should be deleted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to randomly grab an `Idea` each time, you can use the more expressive `Idea.all.sample`.

To grab a random number, you also don't necessarily need Faker, you can just do `rand(3) + 1`.

If `round_id` is a column in the `ideas` table, you'll need to actually save the model on each iteration for the changes you're making to persist.

One faster way you could do this is:

```
Idea.all.sample(7).each do |idea|
   idea.update(round_id: rand(3) + 1)
end
```

This grabs 7 random `Ideas`, iterates over them, and assigns each a random round_id between 1 and 3.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I wish I could have come to this conclusion before posting, but I obviously have a ton more learning to do.

Comment: Note that `Idea.all.sample` fetches *all* `Idea`s from the database. This might become expensive.

Comment: This should be much  better => `rand(1..3)`